# Erro query update set

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

A `$query1` e `$query2` funcionam, mas a `$query1a` de update não está setando, alguém sabe dizer se é erro de sintaxe?

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','rr','4ai','rr') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');


$query1 = "INSERT INTO sac (data,nome,email,empresa,telefone,cidade,assunto,categoria,mensagem) VALUES (now(),'$nome','$email','$empresa','$telefone','$cidade','$assunto','$categoria','$mensagem')";
    mysqli_query($conexao,$query1);

$d = date("dmY");
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
$prot = "SAC".$d.$id; 
//echo $id;


$query1a = "UPDATE sac SET protocolo=$prot WHERE id=$id";
    mysqli_query($conexao,$query1a) or die ('erro cadastrar proto');


$query2 = "INSERT INTO status (solicitacao_solistatus,status_solistatus,setor,data_solistatus,resposta) VALUES ('$id','Em andamento','SAC',now(),'$resposta')";
    mysqli_query($conexao,$query2);
```

Comment: Ocorre algum erro? Se ocorre, qual é o erro?

Comment: faça um `echo $query1a;` o sql está correto? Teste no phpMyAdmin workbanch ou algo assim

Answer (score 1):

Só faltava aspas '' na variável $prot
Obrigada aí aos que responderam, vlw